# How do I retrieve the value of an attribute in a parent if one of the elements of a child equals to a value?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I'm new to C# and LINQ. I have this XML file which I'm trying to receive values from.

```
<Transitions>
    <Transition Name="A-B" To="B" From="A" 
      <Triggers>
        <Trigger Type="Command" NameRef="1" />
      </Triggers>
      <Conditions>
        <Condition Type="Always" NameRef="" ConditionInversion="false" />
      </Conditions>
      <Designer />
    </Transition>
    <Transition Name="A-C" To="C" From="A" 
      <Triggers>
        <Trigger Type="Command" NameRef="2" />
      </Triggers>
      <Conditions>
        <Condition Type="Always" NameRef="" ConditionInversion="false" />
      </Conditions>
      <Designer X="1095" Y="171" />
    </Transition>
</Transitions>
```

I want my function to return the value of "To" based on the values of "From" and "NameRef". Example if my arguments are From = A and NameRef = 2, it would return C.

I'm using LINQ expressions to retrieve the values but I'm stuck on how retrieve the value of "To" while I'm already querying for the value of "NameRef".

My code is something like this but it's obviously now working:

```
public static string readFromXMLobj(string node, Process xmlobj, string[] args = null)
{
   switch(node)
     {
        case "NextPage":
            transition = xmlobj.Transitions.SelectMany(c => c.Transition); 
            string results = transition.Where(a => a.From == args[0]).Where(b => b.Triggers.FirstOrDefault().Trigger.Select(c => c.NameRef).ToString() == args[1]).Select(d => d.To).FirstOrDefault();
            break;
     }
     return results
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Use System.Xml library and parse it through that. It would be a perfect solution for that and would run with 100% for every case.

Comment: var results = doc.Descendants("Transition").Where(x =>
                ((string)x.Attribute("From") == "A") &&
                (x.Descendants("Trigger").Select(y => (int)y.Attribute("NameRef") == 2).FirstOrDefault())
            ).ToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am suggesting you to use System.Xml library to parse the same xml string:-

1.)Put your complete string into str variable.
2.)Take XmlDocument object and load the str file.
3.)Pick those nodes using "selectNodes" and "selectSingleNode" functions.

```
            XmlDocument responseDoc = new XmlDocument();
            responseDoc.LoadXml(str);
            XmlNodeList nodes = responseDoc.SelectNodes("Transitions/Transition");
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                if (node.Attributes.Count > 0 && node.Attributes["From"] != null)
                {
                    string temp = string.Empty;
                    if (node.Attributes["To"] != null)
                        temp = node.Attributes["To"].Value;
                    if (string.Compare(node.Attributes["From"].Value, "A", true) == 0)
                    {
                        XmlNode nodeset = node.SelectSingleNode("Triggers/Trigger");
                        if (nodeset != null && nodeset.Attributes.Count > 0 &&
                            nodeset.Attributes["NameRef"] != null)
                        {
                            if (string.Compare(nodeset.Attributes["NameRef"].Value, "2", true) == 0)
                                Console.WriteLine(temp);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

You can call a method and pass the variable according to your requirements.